# button not disabled after tick event end

Tags: asp.net, timer

```
<div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" OnTick="ontick" runat="server">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Text="button" ID="btnText" />
    </div>

protected void ontick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        TextBox1.Text = "1";        
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        btnText.Enabled = false;
    }
```

**button not disabled after tick event end**

Comment: Snce the button is outside the `UpdatePanel`, it's not affected by the async postback. Try changing `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to `PostBackTrigger`; this will refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally correct behavior, since button is **outside** of the update panel. Please include it inside of ContentTemplate, or create new update panel, in which you will wrap this button and have set Update type to Always (i think it's default behavior)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put the button inside the content template so it will disabled when the update panel is updated.